# Concurrent requests from PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-ebs

I want to work out the logic on following requirements.

XML Publisher Data Definition will fire the beforeReport trigger which calls function that returns TRUE or FALSE.

This function is contained within PL/SQL package. 
Within this function first the concurrent request will be sent in order to SQL*Load some data into APPS database table. After, report will show records that didn't pass. SQL*Loader is called as concurrent request with Executable that is HOST(shell script).

Somehow the RETURN(sucess or failure) from SQL*Loader should be checked within PL/SQL. Meaning, I need some output parameters from concurrent request? Or?

If SUCCESS then it proceeds forward. If FAILED, it should check the database table to see if there are old records to process.

So here the next 'event' follows which SHOULD happen in beforeReport trigger. Call procedure which I already have, which performs some validations upon table records and calls API to create person within HZ_PARTIES table. But depending on SQL*Loader return status:

-if there are old record, then call API, but return WARNING status of concurrent request. What's the best way to return WARNING in this case?

-if there are no old records then API is not submitted but (execution)report will show that SQL*Loader failed and there is no data to show.

In short, I need to work out how to structure functions and procedures, that is:

Say, I put the function which is called in beforeReport trigger as public, and then within this function everything else happens: 
1) SQL*Loader concurrent request - but is it better to put this into some procedure or nested function and then call it within the above "main" function?
Then, if its success which I get as out parameter, step 2:

2) Validation and API - can I put this inside private procedure or function as well, as above?

3) Report will be shown. Containing results from two prior steps.

I just need some clarification on this what is best to do. I can clear up some questions further if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: This really isn't appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you've got code that's broken people here can probably help. But doing your design work? That's asking a bit much. You might try it on codereview.stackexchange.com, but even then it's CODE REVIEW, not DESIGN REVIEW. Sorry - I don't know what to suggest. Best of luck.

Comment: In addition to what @BobJarvis has suggested, you should probably visit [Oracle Community Forums](https://community.oracle.com/welcome) and I would also suggest that you consider reading up on best practice or perhaps obtain some formal training. It sounds to me like you are perhaps missing some fundamental skills for working with eBusiness Suite. "SQLLoad some data into APPS database table." - this kind of operation is not supported in EBS; you should be using standard, public APIs or FNDLOAD tools etc.

Comment: Correction - SQLLoad data into temporary/staging table. I use standard APIs otherwise. But sure, I'll look elsewhere, while coming closer to solutions in the meantime. The questions were brief actually, I didn't ask for solutions or design, I asked for few hints, for example what can old values possibly mean in the context that I explained. I also said that I can clear up on specifics if needed, just to get one or two questions answered, no more, no less.

Comment: And I didn't know that re-evaluating program logic on stack overflow is forbidden.

Comment: I figured it out btw. Goodbye.